# R: Merge several categorical of one variable into factor

Tags: r, categorical-data

My dataset is from a repeated measure design. Now I would like to create a subset with a new categorical variable. In this subset several factorial values of one meausred categorical variable should be merged into a new factor.

I have a data set that looks similar to this:

```
participant_nr condition value
01 B 13
01 C 20
01 A 60
01 D 11
01 E 17
02 C 18
02 A 7
02 B 12
02 D 11
02 E 15
```

I would like to create a new subset, where

1. all rows are excluded where condition = A
2. a new column is create with a new factor. This variable should have two factors. "low" when condition = B or C and "high" when condition = D or E.

Thus, the subset should look something like this:

```
participant_nr condition value new_factor
    01 B 13 low
    01 C 20 low
    01 D 11 high
    01 E 17 high
    02 C 18 low
    02 B 12 low
    02 D 11 high
    02 E 15 high
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for base r or tidyverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can `filter` and `mutate` with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!condition == "A") %>%
  mutate(new_factor = case_when(
    condition %in% c("B", "C") ~ "low",
    condition %in% c("D", "E") ~ "high"))
```

Output

```
 participant_nr condition value new_factor
1              1         B    13        low
2              1         C    20        low
3              1         D    11       high
4              1         E    17       high
5              2         C    18        low
6              2         B    12        low
7              2         D    11       high
8              2         E    15       high
```

Comment: Thanks alot – That's a very elegant way

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do it, through base R or through the popular tidyverse packages:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'participant_nr condition value
01 B 13
01 C 20
01 A 60
01 D 11
01 E 17
02 C 18
02 A 7
02 B 12
02 D 11
02 E 15', header = T)

# base R
df_new <- subset(df, condition != 'A')
df_new$new_factor <- ifelse(df_new$condition %in% c('B', 'C'), 'low', 'high')

# tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

df_new <- df %>% 
  filter(condition != 'A') %>% 
  mutate(new_factor = ifelse(condition %in% c('B', 'C'), 'low', 'high'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` approach

```r
data.table::setDT(f)

f[condition!='A',.SD,list(new_factor=ifelse(condition %in% c('B','C'),'Low','High')), .SDcols=c(1:3)]
```